# Laravel implementing Instagram followers and followings relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-relations

[Here](https://medium.com/geekculture/followers-mechanism-in-laravel-5f78bcc0adde) i see a documented how can we implementing `Instagram` follower mechanism, but that had some problem which i fixed them and now `follow` and `unfollow` work fine. for example:

```php
Route::get('follow', function () {
    $user = User::find(1);
    $account = Account::find(2);
    $user->follow($account);
});

Route::get('unfollow', function () {
    $user = User::find(1);
    $account = Account::find(2);
    $user->unfollow($account);
});
```

but this code doesn't have getting user has how many `followings` such as list or count and i try to add on that but i can't successfully do that

by this code i can get user followers count:

```php
return $user->withCount(['followers'])->find(1)
```

or list of all user `followers:

```php
return \App\Models\Follower::query()->whereMorphedTo('userable', User::find(1))->get();
```

`Followable` interface:

```php
interface Followable
{
    public function followers(): MorphMany;
}
```

`HasFollowed` trait:

```php
trait HasFollowed
{
    public function follow(Followable $followable): void
    {
        if ($this->hasFollowed($followable)) {
            return;
        }
        app(Follower::class)
            ->user()->associate($this->id)
            ->userable()->associate($this)
            ->followable()->associate($followable)
            ->save();
    }

    public function unfollow(Followable $followable): void
    {
        $followable->followers()
            ->whereMorphedTo('userable', $this)
            ->delete();
    }

    public function hasFollowed(Followable $followable): bool
    {
        if (!$followable->exists) {
            return false;
        }

        return $followable->followers()->whereRelation('user', 'users.id', $this->id)->exists();
    }
}
```

`HasFollower` trait:

```php
trait HasFollower
{
    public function followers(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Follower::class, 'followable');
    }
}
```

`Account` model as user pages in instagram:

```php
class Account extends Model implements Followable
{
    use HasFactory, HasFollower;
}
```

`User` model:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes, HasFollowed;

    public function account(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Account::class);
    }

    public function followers(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Follower::class);
    }

    public function followings(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Follower::class);
    }
}
```

`followers` migration:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('followers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
        $table->morphs('userable');
        $table->morphs('followable');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: `User::withCount(['followers'])->find(1);`

Comment: @JSTECH i need to get user `followings`, not `follwers`

Comment: Just called followings: `User::withCount(['followings'])->find(1);`

Comment: @JSTECH so how can i get all `followings` list array?

Comment: @JSTECH this code: `return \App\Models\Follower::query()->whereMorphedTo('userable', User::find(1))->get()` return all `followers` list, not `followings`

Comment: What's the database structure of followers table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248494/discussion-between-doldurma-and-js-tech).

Answer (score 0):

Use trait and implement Followable as well in your User model instead of defining followers and followings method manually.

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements Followable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes, HasFollower, HasFollowed;
}
```

Also same thing in Account model:

```
class Account extends Model implements Followable
{
    use HasFactory, HasFollower, HasFollowed;
}
```

`Followable` interface:

```
interface Followable
{
    public function followers(): MorphMany;
    public function followings(): MorphMany;
}
```

`HasFollower` trait

```
trait HasFollower
{
    public function followers(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Follower::class, 'userable');
    }

    public function followings(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Follower::class, 'followable');
    }
}
```

Get followers and followings list and count:

```
$user = User::with(['followers', 'followings'])->withCount(['followers', 'followings'])->find(1);

$user->followers;
$user->followings;

$user->followers_count;
$user->followings_count;
```